# How to remove wine broken icons in dashboard

Tags: 15.10

How can I remove a broken wine application? Please check the image below.

[image: Ubuntu start menu]

I am using ubuntu 15.10. and wine-1.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to remove the shortcut, go to `~/.local/share/applications/` and delete the `.desktop` file you want to be gone.

If you want to remove the windows program itself, run `wine uninstaller`

Details in [Wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ).